# Run only once a code in locationlistener

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2, locationlistener

I would like to run a code (get route to nearest location) only once, when location is fixed by the LocationListener, but each time the location gets an update the code runs. If i stop the location listener once the location is fixed my location will not get updates. Is it possible to run a code only once inside a locationlistener? How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put a boolean in the location listener. If it runs first time, make the boolean as false, so next time the same code will not run in the location of the listener.

```
boolean isFirstTime = true;
```

At the location listener, use the following:

```
if(isFirstTime){
   // Do your task which you want to do

   // and change flag to false.
   isFirstTime = false;
}
```

I hope this will help you.